# Windows 7 not connecting to Samba Shares

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-12.04, samba

I'm setting up a home server using Ubuntu Server 12.04Lts and I'm trying to connect my Windows 7 desktop to it. However when I try to connect from my windows 7 PC I get a message saying "Windows cannot access \Unbutuserver\Shared Drive Check the spelling of the name"

I'm using the following configuration file

> [global]
>   workgroup = WORKGROUP #(Set this to your Windows workgroup)
>   netbios = WORKGROUP #(Set this to your Windows workgroup)
>   security = share
>   [Shared Drive] #(Set this to the name you want the shared folder to have)
>   comment = entire shared drive #(Comments about the shared folder)
>   path = /netstorage #(Path to the shared folder or mount-point of harddrive)
>   read only = no
>   guest ok = yes
>   writable = yes

When I run testparm I get the following

> Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
>   rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
>
> Processing section "[glbal]"
>
> Global parameter workgroup found in service section!
>
> Unknown parameter encountered: "netbios"
>
> Ignoring unknown parameter "netbios"
>
> Global parameter security found in service section!
>
> WARNING: No path in service glbal - making it unavailable!
>
> NOTE: Service glbal is flagged unavailable.
>
> Processing section "[Shared Drive]"
>
> Loaded services file OK.
>
> Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
>
> Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions
>   [global]
>          idmap config * : backend = tdb
>   [glbal]
>          available = No
>   [Shared Drive]
>          comment = entire shared drive #(Comments about the shared folder)
>
> ```
>    path = /netstorage #(Path to the shared folder or mount-point of harddrive)
>
>    read only = No
>
>    guest ok = Yes
> ```

All I'm trying to do is make the "Netstorage" directory, where my RAID5 array is mounted, available to my Windows PC over the network.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Check `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, that "[glbal]" doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with Win7 + Samba. Try these registry tweaks, worked for me:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanManWorkstation\Parameters]

DWORD DomainCompatibilityMode 1
DWORD DNSNameResolutionRequired 0
```

Source: [Samba Wiki](http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Registry_changes_for_NT4-style_domains)

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me. I'm still getting the same error. I'm thinking that it's possible the error might be on the Windows PC side of things, so I'm going to try to reformat my desktop to see if that helps.

Comment: Reformatting has not helped the issue as far as I can tell, I tried redoing your registry tip and unfortunately it still did not help. Thank you for your assistance though.